# Does there exist a Python implementation of the Royston-Parmar model for survival analysis?

Tags: r, python, survival, model

I am seeking to perform a survival analysis on a dataset with healthcare outcomes for patients who are tracked across time. There are many models to choose from when performing survival analysis, but in my project, I have been tasked with using the [Royston-Parmar model](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/sim.1203). I have found three Python libraries for survival analysis.

1. PySurvival
2. scikit-survival
3. SurPyval
4. lifelines

They are all excellent and offer many models, but not Royston-Parmar.

I have scoured StackOverflow, google search and google scholar, and I am only able to find an R implementation of the Royston-Parmar model with [flexsurv](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexsurv/vignettes/flexsurv.pdf), but I am only permitted to use Python. It would be useful for me to know if it exists in Python or not, either way. I appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Ilya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in lifelines, but under the `CoxPHFitter`. Here's a small replication of the Royston Parmar paper you linked:

```py
import pandas as pd

from lifelines.datasets import load_lymph_node
from lifelines import CoxPHFitter


### Recreate their dataset
df = load_lymph_node()

df["T"] = df["rectime"] / 365.0
df["E"] = df["censrec"]

# see paper for where these come from
df["linear_predictor"] = (
    1.79 * (df["age"] / 50) ** (-2)
    - 8.02 * (df["age"] / 50) ** (-0.5)
    + 0.5 * (df["grade"] >= 2).astype(int)
    - 1.98 * np.exp(-0.12 * df["nodes"])
    - 0.058 * (df["prog_recp"] + 1) ** 0.5
    - 0.394 * df["hormone"]
)
df["binned_lp"] = pd.qcut(df["linear_predictor"], np.linspace(0, 1, 4), labels=["good", "medium", "poor"])


### Create spline model and fit
cph = CoxPHFitter(
    baseline_estimation_method="spline", 
    n_baseline_knots=4
)
cph.fit(df, "T", "E", formula="binned_lp").print_summary(columns=["coef"])
```

Comment: Thank you. I reviewed the documentation and you are correct. Warm regards.